# Node.js Connection to Squelize

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

i want connection to mssql but it cant't

search google , search stackOverFlow

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1433
    at Promise.catch.error (c:\git Repository\nodeStudy001\P007_Express\learn-express\learn-sequelize\learn-sequelize\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\connection-manager.js:132:19)
    at tryCatcher (c:\git Repository\nodeStudy001\P007_Express\learn-express\learn-sequelize\learn-sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (c:\git Repository\nodeStudy001\P007_Express\learn-express\learn-sequelize\learn-sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:517:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (c:\git Repository\nodeStudy001\P007_Express\learn-express\learn-sequelize\learn-sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:574:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (c:\git Repository\nodeStudy001\P007_Express\learn-express\learn-sequelize\learn-sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:619:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (c:\git Repository\nodeStudy001\P007_Express\learn-express\learn-sequelize\learn-sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:695:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (c:\git Repository\nodeStudy001\P007_Express\learn-express\learn-sequelize\learn-sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:12)
```

Comment: You should provide some information how you try to connect DB, some code exempla etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. You didn't start your database - Check this one.
2. Wrong database config check db config - Check your database config.

   var sequelize = new Sequelize(your db config)